# org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not initialize a collection

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss

Please, advise on what could be possible cause of this error (`which is coming while downloading thousand of rows`).

**Error:**

```
org.jboss.util.NestedSQLException: Transaction TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: afd014e:ebc0:56d64a1d:72 status: ActionStatus.ABORTED > cannot proceed STATUS_ROLLEDBACK; - nested throwable: (javax.transaction.RollbackException: Transaction TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: afd014e:ebc0:56d64a1d:72 status: ActionStatus.ABORTED > cannot proceed STATUS_ROLLEDBACK)
```

Comment: I found that download is working for some rows like 5 or 10, but fails for many.

Answer (score 0):

Bro. Show of some of your code. How you connect to db, fetching rows ? 
IMHO: You are reaching limit of concurrent connections to DB. So probably you are starting transactions somewhere in you code bu you are not utilizing it properly.